# How to load custom plugin in py.test

Tags: python, pytest

I am having an issue with a custom plugin I am writing to collect py.test results in a rst-formatted file. In the end I would like to include this file into Sphinx docs.

I have written my plugin in the `myplugin.py` module which is in the current working directory. I then call

```
py.test -p myplugin ../mytool/test
```

which ends in an `ImportError: No module named myplugin`.

I also tried calling it like

```
py.test -p .myplugin ../mytool/test
```

like a relative import, but without success.

#### How can I properly use the plugin?

The [Docs](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#plugin-discovery-order-at-tool-startup) give the following information about plugin detection:

> #### Plugin discovery order at tool startup pytest loads plugin modules at tool startup in the following way:
>
> - by loading all builtin plugins
> - by loading all plugins registered through setuptools entry points.
> - by pre-scanning the command line for the -p name option and loading
>     the specified plugin before actual command line parsing.
> - by loading all conftest.py files as inferred by the command line
>     invocation:
>
> if no test paths are specified use current dir as a test path if
>   exists, load conftest.py and test*/conftest.py relative to the
>   directory part of the first test path. Note that pytest does not find
>   conftest.py files in deeper nested sub directories at tool startup. It
>   is usually a good idea to keep your conftest.py file in the top level
>   test or project root directory.
>
> - by recursively loading all plugins specified by the pytest_plugins
>     variable in conftest.py files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plugin is not importable it is because it is not on `sys.path`.  Try explicitly adding it using the `PYTHONPATH` variable:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dir/of/myplugin py.test -p myplugin ../mytool/test
```

Comment: Indeed that did the trick. Thanks. I thought the current working dir is always in the python path by default.

Comment: That's only the case if you set `PYTHONPATH` to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a plugin from the current directory, you can also just invoke `pytest` with `python -m` instead:

```
python -m pytest -p myplugin
```

This way you don't need to set `PYTHONPATH` explicitly. From [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html):

> ### Invoking `pytest` versus `python -m pytest`
>
> Running pytest with `python -m pytest [...]` instead of `pytest [...]`
>   yields nearly equivalent behaviour, except that the former call will
>   add the current directory to `sys.path. See also [Calling pytest through
>   python -m pytest.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#cmdline)